# Is there a link between intelligence and mental disturbances?

Tags: intelligence, creativity

Is there a link between high intelligence or creativity, measured with currently valid psychometrics, such as IQ tests or tests of creativity and mental disorders like depression, anxiety, or bipolarity?

Comment: This is not a serious answer just a an idea around some in the field, the smarter (far away from the norm) you are, the largest the chance your wiring is not normal, and thus the larger the chance that something else is going wrong.

Comment: I believe a link exists.  Schizophrenia in particular and (leaps of) Creativity are thought to have gone hand-in-hand throughout the evolution of the human brain.

Comment: Yes. I believe a link exists too. There was (and are) a lot of important scientists with some mental disturbs. I think that a smarter mind can distort reality and relations with other people.

Answer (score -1):

I like Mr Smitherson's consideration, which is indeed in the realm of possibilities. I haven't read a definitive study yet, I will search and return soon.

However, for further consideration to the question from a psychological/cognitive perception I posit the following:

Persons with abnormal, on the high scale of intelligence, would perhaps have more varied considerations when presented with a situation or when presented with a problem.

People with a higher IQ would normally think deeper into a problem. This would activate more brain cells, and drain the brain of the chemicals it uses to function. This would lead to imbalance.

The second consideration is that people who are more intelligent, would think about things further. To expand on that idea, since I am not the best at explaining stuff, I'll give an example: a person, of high IQ, is presented with information on global warming, a normal (for the sake of argument) person would take in the information and perhaps think "this isn't good" and leave it there. The person of higher IQ would thinking further about the implications, perhaps research and may find the situation hopeless.

Constant barrage of these situations may lead to lower moods and the elevated hopeless thinking lead to depression fueled by anxiety for the future.

This is what I would consider to be the cause behind any correlation between intelligence and mental illness in the form or depression/anxiety (these two conditions feed each other into a spiral)

Comment: The rules of stack exchange require that you back up your suggestions with references, preferably scientifically reviewed references. The following reference my be a useful starting point for referencing which could improve your answer: http://archpsyc.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=481989